# Copying a list of subscribed data in System center orchestrator

Tags: orchestration, scorch

I'm using System Center Orchestrator 2012, and I have a generic error handler which is connected to all the activities in my runbook.

I have subscribed to a list of published data as a parameter in this error handler, which looks like this:

Activity Name : {Activity Name from "Monitor File"}{Activity Name from "Move file"}.......

What I need to do is copy this list of subscribed data and do a search and replace to change the Activity Name parameter to something else, say Error Message. Whenever I copy this list of variables, I get gibberish when I paste it

```
\`d.T.~Ed/{598EBDFA-BF5B-4B77-8156-E6FA6ECD0CE1}.Object.Name\`d.T.~Ed/\`d.T.~Ed/{6838D741-DF8E-4C25-8C28-D06A52F67D36}.Object.Name\`d.T.~Ed/\`d.T.~Ed/{D1D9BBE6-5AAF-4D8F-A98A-1A8BDD977E7E}.Object.Name\`d.T.~Ed/\`d.T.~Ed/{9EC92323-1B9B-4D06-88E9-A97BA525CF5A}.Object.Name\`d.T.~Ed/\`d.T.~Ed/{FAD32B4C-92CC-40BD-837A-4C5F22C2E018}.Object.Name\`d.T.~Ed/\`d.T.~Ed/{DFF7A110-ACFD-4377-AFEC-16B5BEC8BFF4}.Object.Name\`d.T.~Ed/\`d.T.~Ed/{139ACC4E-CF6D-4EEE-BD88-9DC1E0FC2038}.Object.Name\`d.T.~Ed/\`d.T.~Ed/{1484789C-BB37-4507-AD21-E367665E0BE6}.Object.Name\`d.T.~Ed/\`d.T.~Ed/{01EA8BD0-69C5-4959-86DB-29FAD34D144A}.Object.Name\`d.T.~Ed/\`d.T.~Ed/{A60C582B-5DD0-41F7-BB0A-B5D71C3B9ECB}.Object.Name\`d.T.~Ed/\`d.T.~Ed/{1FA1E2D6-813D-4A4A-A5CD-07EB2AD4AC9B}.Object.Name\`d.T.~Ed/
```

Is there a way to simply copy the text? If not, I will have to click on all the activities over and over again to subscribe to different types of data.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gibberish you're seeing is how Orchestrator translates the published data and variables to the database guids.  Copying this out will always translate to the DB guids, so there's no way to do a copy/replace with "activity name" for "Error Summary".  You'd need to subscribe to each activity's data or look up all of the guids which probably wouldn't be easier.

Unfortunately, setting up the error handling process in SCOrch becomes tedious to be effective.

I use a separate email linked to each activity to give more information based on the error message.  I don't like to use generic error emails with published data from multiple activities since it doesn't necessarily give all the useful information you need (or an end user will be able to understand).

Comment: Yea, I've spent quite some time to explore if there is a better way to handle errors apart from attaching an error handler to each and every activity. I did come across this http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/scogeneral/thread/f7fb8ee3-c591-4dfe-b480-c15040ea6fd1/ but it doesn't help if you want to subscribe to the activity name as well.